# Host computer freezes on kernel loading message. How do I find out why?

Tags: logging, kernel

My computer freezes on the kernel loading message pretty much everytime the computer has been left off for too long (not sure how long, because its not 100% reproductible.)

reseting will mostly go back to the error. shutting off and on, will mostly fix it. again, nothing 100% certain.

2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP, with a stock install of debian 6 squeeze. Also happened with the last versions of Ubuntu.

I think it's hardware related because in the logs after kernel bootup is the Raid startup... my drives are not high end and in fact I just had to replace one (I'm clueless so far).

So, the question is: **How do I gather more information on why this may be happening so I can fix the problem?**

*EDIT*: Forgot to remove the quiet option... thought it was freezeing up before any kernel output...

So, without the quiet option if freezes on two places: One right after the last line of USB initialization; two other times on the line after the USB initialization... which is the ATA

syslog.1 obviously contains data from last good boot as this problem ocurs before filesystem init

Comment: Replace your CMOS battery.

Comment: i may try that... any rationale for why it may help?

Comment: that solved :) even though not really the answer to the question... Thanks!

Comment: Well that's why it was just a comment not an answer. I missed your reply... I figured a quick comment is better than no answer at all.